# Is it blasphemy to question Islam?

Tags: quran, hadith, sunni, islamic-philosophy, shirk

Salam,

I'm Muslim, I've always been curious with a lot of imaginations, questions about everything (religions, music, mathematics..etc) even if I'm not as smart as 90% of people I know, they are AWAY more intelligent than me. (sorry for the other 10% but I love them too).

The thing is : I'm always asking questions about things I face in order (I think) to "control" (it's not exactly the word I'm looking for) those things.

When I'm asking about science, space and galaxies, history, etc people are okay, my friends and me can talk hours about stuff like that BUT when it comes to ask about details of things in Islam, or God, my friends not only do not answer me but they talk about the piano that will fall on us (compared to cartoons situation) and if I'm asking my mother, she became upset.

Is there any verse of Qur'an or hadith that talks about a certain degree of asking or a point that we should not exceed?

At what moment our questions become blasphemous?

Once again, I'm asking questions, I'm wondering in order to understand and nothing else.

Salam.

Comment: You are free to ask anything, but there are some kind of discussions a Muslim shouldn't be part of according Quran (for example if it is a kind of blasphemy or mocking on Allah and his Prophet (pbuh)) ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Is it blasphemy to question Islam?

No, it is not blasphemy to question your belief in Islam. The companions of the Prophet (pbuh) often asked him questions regarding Islam. During the time of the prophet, people often came to the prophet (pbuh) to ask him questions about Islam.

> Narrated Abdullah bin Ammar: I saw the Prophet (ﷺ) near the Jamra
> and **the people were asking him questions (about religious problems)**...
>
> Narrated Ibn Abu Mulaika: Whenever `Aisha (the wife of the Prophet)
> heard anything which she did not understand, she used to ask again
> till she understood it completely...
>
> Narrated Abu Musa: A man came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and asked, "O Allah's
> Messenger (ﷺ)! What kind of fighting is in Allah's cause? ...
>
> Narrated Abu Sa`id Al-Khudri: Some women requested the Prophet (ﷺ) to
> fix a day for them as the men were taking all his time. On that he
> promised them one day for religious lessons and commandments...
>
> Narrated Abdullah bin Amr bin Al `Aas: Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) stopped
> (for a while near the Jimar) at Mina during his last Hajj for the
> people and they **were asking him questions**...

### Is there any verse of Qur'an or hadith that talks about a certain degree of asking or a point that we should not exceed?

There is a verse which says "O you who believe! Ask not about things which, if made plain to you, may cause you trouble". Allah almighty, may he be gorified and exalted, says in the Qur'an (interpretation of the meaning) :

> [5:101] “O you who believe! Ask not about things which, if made plain to you,
> may cause you trouble. But if you ask about them while the Quran is
> being revealed, they will be made plain to you. Allah has forgiven
> that, and Allah is Oft-Forgiving, Most Forbearing”

But this prohibition applies specifically to the time of the Prophet (while the Quran was being revealed). This verse forbade the companions to ask the Prophet (peace be upon him) about matters that Allah had not said anything in the Qur'an. It also forbade them to ask about things that they didn't know of and if they came to know of them it could upset them `(e.g questions like, "who is my father?", "what did my father think of me")`. This prohibition doesn't apply anymore.

### At what moment our questions become blasphemous?

There is no evidence in the Qur'an or Sunnah that limits what we can ask. So, there is no "moment" when our questions become blasphemous. Asking questions is encouraged Islam. Allah says in the Qur'an (interpretation of the meaning) :

> [16:43] And We sent not before you except men to whom We revealed [Our
> message]. **So ask the people of the message if you do not know.**

---

> Narrated Anas bin Malik: One day Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) came out
> (before the people) and Abdullah bin Hudhafa stood up and asked (him)
> "Who is my father?" The Prophet (ﷺ) replied, "Your father is Hudhafa."
> **The Prophet (ﷺ) told them repeatedly (in anger) to ask him anything
> they liked.** `Umar knelt down before the Prophet (ﷺ) and said thrice,
> "We accept Allah as (our) Lord and Islam as (our) religion and
> Muhammad as (our) Prophet." After that the Prophet (ﷺ) became silent.