# Who are the "people of the message" in Qur'an 16:43?

Tags: tafseer, surat-an-nahl

When I read Rebecca's question [Are Muslims encouraged to read the Bible and/or the Torah? Why or why not?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34839/are-muslims-encouraged-to-read-the-bible-and-or-the-torah-why-or-why-not), it remind me An-Nahl verse 43. As it states:

> And We sent not before you except men to whom We revealed [Our message]. So ask the people of the message if you do not know.
>   [Quran 16:43](https://quran.com/16/43)

Who are these "people of message"? Are they same as 
[people of book](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7/who-are-ahlul-kitab)?

If these people same as "people of book", my interpretation as "getting knowledge from these people is allowed" is wrong?

I read these questions and related answers also and it gives me more confusion because every reader got different understanding from this verse:

- [An answer to "Read Quran with tafseer alone"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/33373/3466)
- [Why Islam contradicts with Quran about the authenticity of Bible?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/why-islam-contradicts-with-quran-about-the-authenticity-of-bible/4268#4268)
- [An answer to "Between Halal and Haram"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/17318/3466)
- [An answer to "How Do Muslims Deal with “Difficult” Parts of Prophet Mohammed's Life?"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/12791/3466)
- [An answer to "Is it blasphemy to question Islam?"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/31101/3466)
- [An answer to "Is ijtihad open in Islam (Sunni view)?"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/26329/3466)

Comment: If I got you right you want a tafsir of verse 16:43 which reflects the "most" meaning or interpretation of "ahl a-dhikr/people of knowled/message"?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Yes, I see lots of different approach/explanation but these give me confusion..

Comment: Maybe an interpretation could be based on a historical back ground: As long as Quran was not fully revealed beside the Prophet himself ahl-al-kitab were possible people of knowledge, once it was fully revealed in first place people of knowledge were those who gain knowledge via Quran. But I also read that our Prophet encouraged his companions to ask ahl-al-kitab... but all of this is my reflection!

Comment: The translation more should be 'people of remembrance' meaning people who actually know their religion.

Comment: So, it's basically saying, A message came before you so ask the people who remember [that message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by others in the comment section, the Arabic words used is "Ahl Adh-Dhikr"  or 'People of the Dhikr'. 'Dhikr' means 'reminder' or 'remembrance' or 'message' [loosely]. The first interpretation is that this means 'People of the Books'.

Tafsir Ibn Katheer says:

```
It was reported by Mujahid from Ibn Abbas that;
what is meant by Ahl Adh-Dhikr is the People of
the Book.
```